# What is the point of the daily limit?

Tags: support

I got 199 reputation points today, and it seemed a little strange, because it just stopped at 199. I read up, and I discovered that there is a limit at 200 points per day. Why?

Comment: Congrats. I'd love to get 200 rep in a day.

Comment: yes, but I really got a good bit more, so it felt a little strange that they were taken from me. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The *Daily Reputation Limit* is primarily designed for one purpose:

- to make you **take a break**

The last thing this community wants is burnt out users. In addition, it also prevents a handful of users' reputation on the site from shooting upward much too quickly. Which makes it more realistic for a newcomer to join the first page of the reputation leagues. Not that it's important. :)

Now, this reasoning, one might say, is retrofitted to the site. Generally it's just good practice in [game mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification) and [karma systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reputation_system) to never have *any* unbounded behaviours. It also rather takes some of the seriousness out of the 'competition'.

Lastly it makes users come back. A user who posts a great answer now and again, for many months, is much more helpful than one who shoots up the reputation ladder within two months, never to be seen again after he's entered the gruelling dungeon that is the top 10. Where it gets harder and harder to climb places.

Anyway,

take a break. :-)

See also:

- [MSO: What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap)
- [MSO: Does a Rep Cap discourage participation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54695/does-a-rep-cap-discourage-participation)
- [MSO: How does limiting my ability to gain reputation for upvotes (200 per 24 hours) actually "level the playing field"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90865/how-does-limiting-my-ability-to-gain-reputation-for-upvotes-200-per-24-hours-ac)
- [Blog: Daily Dose of Daily Reputation Cap](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/daily-dose-of-daily-reputation-ca/)