# Upvotes with no reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the point of the daily limit?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1737/what-is-the-point-of-the-daily-limit)

I have received about 28 upvotes on answers on askubuntu so far today, but only 20 of them are showing the +10 for reputation. The others are in the list, but have no +10 next to them, and my reputation page shows I've only received 200 reputation today, but of course, all the ~28 upvotes are listed. The count at the top of the page also has only increased by the 200 reputation, missing the extra ~80. What is causing this?

Comment: Congrats on getting those 28 upvotes :)  The reasoning behind what you see is in the link now in your question.

Comment: Alot of rep on different questions in such a short time period is weird, don't be surprised if the anti-cheat kicks in and invalidates it.